# Click cell to copy to clipboard in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, onclick, copy

Is there anyway to copy by just one click in google sheet?

Same like this in google sheets

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAfpxJe1jUg

I have VBA code for excel.

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A9")) Is Nothing Then
Target.Copy
End If
End Sub

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). There is no easy way to access your computer's clipboard from within code that runs in a Google Sheet. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74914442/edit) your question to clarify what you are trying to _accomplish_ — putting stuff in the clipboard sounds like a _means_ to reach some goal rather than being a goal in itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking cannot be done, because Google Apps Script runs on Google's servers rather than in your computer, and there is no access to local resources such as the clipboard.

What you *can* do is use an [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) simple trigger to detect when the user selects a cell. To do stuff when the selected cell is in the range `A1:A9`, use this pattern:

```js
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the selection changes in the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Event} e The onSelectionChange event object.
* @see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee
*/
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 1 // column A
    || e.range.rowStart > 9) {
    return;
  }
  const value = e.range.getValue();
  e.source.toast(`You selected cell ${e.range.getA1Notation()} with value '${value}'.`);
  // do what you want with the value, observing these restrictions:
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/74914595/13045193
}
```

Note that this simple trigger requires a reload of the spreadsheet as outlined in its documentation, and that the things you can do in its runtime context are limited by many [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). Further, the fact that Google Apps Script does not have access to your local resources means that you cannot "press **Control+C**" the way you envision.

Comment: The restrictions make onSelectionChange pretty useless for what OP wants to do.

Comment: Indeed they do.